# python - find index of last two numbers in a mixed type list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following list with numbers and nan's:

```
test_list = [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 4.3, 4.5, np.nan, np.nan]
```

How can i find the index of where the last consecutive numbers stops?  For test_list, the code would return 7.

Thanks for your responses

Edit - 
Apologies for not putting this in there.  Rory I appreciate your clarification of where my question fell down.

```
import numbers
import numpy as np

test_list = [1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 4.3, 4.5, np.nan, np.nan]

streak = 0
streak_list = list()
for t in test_list:
    if isinstance(t, numbers.Number) and ~np.isnan(t):
        streak += 1
    else:
        streak = 0
    streak_list.append(streak)
```

This loop produces the following output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
```

Then I have tried this, which is correct in a small test, but I am not 100% confident in.

```
streak_ends = [i for i, e in enumerate(streak_list) if e >= 2]
answer = streak_ends[-1]
```

Not only do I think there is likely a better method for doing this in general, but I think this will be quite slow on a massive data set. It seems like there would be a much more succinct way of finding this.

Comment: `for`... `if`... the usual stuff...

Comment: It is presumptuous to assume that you will get responses without putting any effort into this yourself.

Comment: ok so I'm really not sure about how to got about this. the stuff i have tried has been just as un-pythonic as much as it does not work. if i am unclear, i mean to ask how to find the index of the last list element that is numeric type that is also preceded by a numeric type.

Comment: @fmc100. You should make that very clear in the question, perhaps by providing some input examples where the last integer is alone. Also, please show any attempts you have made so far. They don't have to be successful. You just need to explain what went wrong.

Comment: this better? has to be a better way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two hints that you can use to make your code.

First, you can check if a given Python value `val` is a "regular number" by testing the expression

```
isinstance(val, numbers.Number) and cmath.isfinite(val)
```

That expression will be `True` for regular numbers, `False` for other values. Of course, this must be preceded by `import` statements for the standard modules `numbers` and `cmath`. This expression will make an error for the rare type that is a technical Python Number but does not fall under complex numbers. I can't think of any such type right now so this should work fine for you. If you want to prevent number types such as complex you could modify that expression.

Second, here is a pythonic way to look at consecutive pairs of values in a list, tuple, or any iterator.

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

This comes from the [recipes section of the documentation for itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes). This uses the `tee` and `izip` functions from itertools, so you will also need to import those.

---

Since you have added code of your own, here is one solution. This code tries to be fast for very long lists by working backward from the end and stopping as soon as a pair of consecutive numbers is found. This also avoids copying the list in forward or reverse order. If the original sequence were a Numpy ndarray, a view of the array in reverse order could probably be used to make a faster routine. But here I just assumed a very long Python list.

```
import cmath, numbers

def isnumber(val):
    """Return if a given value is a regular number"""
    return isinstance(val, numbers.Number) and cmath.isfinite(val)

def ndx_consecutive_numbers(asequence):
    """Return the index of the second number in the last pair of
    consecutive numbers in a given sequence. If no such pair of
    consecutive numbers exists, return -1."""
    prev_was_number = False
    for ndx in range(len(asequence)-1, -1, -1):
        if not isnumber(asequence[ndx]):
            prev_was_number = False
        elif prev_was_number:
            return ndx + 1
        else:
            prev_was_number = True
    return -1

print(ndx_consecutive_numbers(
        [1, 2, 3, cmath.nan, 4, cmath.nan, 4.3, 4.5, cmath.nan, cmath.nan]))
print(ndx_consecutive_numbers(
        [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4, (5, 6), 4.3, 4.5, cmath.nan, 5, {}]))
print(ndx_consecutive_numbers(
        [3, cmath.nan, 4, cmath.nan, 4.5, cmath.nan, 5, cmath.nan]))
```

This results in the desired printout,

```
7
7
-1
```

Comment: your first response helped me see a problem in how i was going about it, and have come up with a working solution, but i still think a poor one. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
out = []
for i in range(len(test_list)):
    if isinstance(test[i-1], int) or isinstance(test[i-1], float):
        out += test[i-1]
print('Consecutive numbers stop at index: '+test_list.find(out[len(out)-1])
```

This should work, though you need to look at docs or use Google before asking such a simple question.

Comment: Your code fails, partly because you use a variable `test` that does not exist. There are also other problems. Did you run this code? Also, I believe your test will consider `nan` and `inf` to be "numbers", which the OP clearly does not want. Perhaps you should add an `isfinite` test or two to your `if` statement.